# Importing js file as module in html gives CORS errors in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, import

I have a simple html file:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <script type="module">
    import init from './target/test.js'
    init()
  </script>
</html>
```

And in the target folder a `test.js` file:

```js
function init() {
    console.log("It works");
}

export default init;
```

But when I open the html file with firefox I get the following errors in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/wanne/Bureaublad/hmm/target/test.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///C:/Users/wanne/Bureaublad/hmm/target/test.js”.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://javascript.info/modules-intro), running modules require a HTTP(s) connection and will not work locally:

> If you try to open a web-page locally, via file:// protocol, you’ll
> find that import/export directives don’t work. Use a local web-server,
> such as static-server or use the “live server” capability of your
> editor, such as VS Code Live Server Extension to test modules.

So I'd suggest exactly that and instead of running it locally, use a live server extension from your preferred text editor.